Is $K^\times/F^\times N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ infinite when $L/F$ is a biquadratic extension of a number field $F$?
Let $F$ be a number field, let $L=F(\sqrt{\alpha_1},\sqrt{\alpha_2})$ be a biquadratic extension, and let $K=F(\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2})$.
Question. Is is true that $K^\times/F^\times N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ is infinite ? I am happy to assume that the $F$-quaternion algebra $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is not split, if necessary.
I think I have an argument in the case where $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID. For sake of simplicity, assume that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ are both saqurefree integers which are not congruent to $1$ mod $4$.
Unless I am mistaken, there are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p\nmid 2 \alpha_1\alpha_2,$ $\alpha_1$ is not a square mod $p$ and $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ is a square mod $p$. Since $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID, there exists $\pi_p\in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\pi_p)=\pm p$.
Now, we have following general result.
Fact. Let $u\in K^\times$. Then the class of $u$ in $K^\times/F^\times N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ is trivial if and only if the quaternion $F$-algebra $(\alpha_1,N_{K/F}(u))$ splits.
Now, if $p,q$ are two distinct primes satisfying the previous conditions, we have $(\alpha_1, N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\pi_p\pi_q^{-1}))\simeq (\alpha_1,\pm pq)$.
Since $p\nmid 2\alpha_1$ and $p\neq q$, the residue at $p$ of this quaternion algebra is the squareclass of $\alpha_1$ modulo $p$, which is not trivial.
It follows that the various classes of $\pi_p$ in the quotient group are pairwise distinct and we are done.
It suggests that the answer in the general case is YES, but I was not able to find a proof.
Note that a related question is an old question of mine:
Is $F^\times/N_{L/F}(L^\times)$ non trivial or infinite when $L/F$ is an extension of global fields?
Thanks to the answer in the previous link, we know that  $K^\times/N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ is infinite, but this does not seems to help.
Unfortunately, I am not comfortable enough with Chebotarev and Zeta functions to  see if one could modify the arguments to answer my question.
Here is my attempt for the genera case.
Attempt of proof of the general case. We may assume that tha $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathcal{O}_L$.

the first step is that to convince ourselves that there are infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_F$
such that $\mathfrak{p}\nmid 2\alpha_1$, $\mathfrak{p}$ is inert in $F(\alpha_1)$ and splits in $F(\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2})$.

I think this is true, but I cannot find a convincing argument at the moment (hence the following question: Existence of prime ideals with given splitting in biquadratic extensions)

Let $\mathfrak{P}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{F(\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2})}$ lying above $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\pi_\mathfrak{p}\in\mathfrak{P}\setminus\mathfrak{P}^2$.

Then $v_\mathfrak{p}(N_{K/F}(\pi_p))=1$ (this uses the assumption on $\mathfrak{p}$).
Let $\mathfrak{q}\neq\mathfrak{p}$ satisfying the required conditions. If one may prove that $v_\mathfrak{q}(N_{K/F}(\pi_\mathfrak{p}))=0$, then one may show that $(\alpha_1,N_{K/F}(\pi_\mathfrak{p}\pi_\mathfrak{q}^{-1}))$ is not split, and we would be done.
Unfortunately, I don't see any reason why this should be true in full generality.
Does anyone would have a proof of the general case ? (if it could avoid Zeta functions, it would be nice)

(Apologies, some previous nonsense corrected.)  The following is actually very close to your argument, but where any assumptions on class numbers are removed by passing to finitely many primes and using weak approximation.
Let $S$ be any finite set of primes in $F$ so that:

$v = ww'$ is split in $K/F$.
$v$ is unramified in $L/F$, but not totally split.

That means that $w$ and $w'$ are inert in $L/K$, and so, by local class field theory, there is an isomorphism
$$K^{\times}_w/N_{L_w/K_w}(L^{\times}_w) \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z}$$
given by the valuation modulo $2$ map.
Hence there is a map
$$
\begin{aligned}
K^{\times}/N_{L/K}(L^{\times}) \rightarrow &  \bigoplus_{v \in S} \
(K^{\times}_w/N_{L_w/K_w}) \times (K^{\times}_{w'}/N_{L_{w'}/K_{w'}}) \\
= & \bigoplus_{v \in S}\ (\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^2 \end{aligned}$$
I claim this map is surjective. This follows from the fact that,  for any prime $w$ of $K$, there exists an global element $\pi_w$
in $K$ which has valuation $1$ at $w$ and valuation $0$ (and hence $0$ mod $2$) for any other finite set $S$ of primes (weak approximation).
On the other hand, since $v$ in $F$ splits in $K$, the valuation of any element in $F^{\times}$
is the same at $w$ and $w'$, and so the image of $F^{\times}$ consists of diagonal elements.
Thus there is a surjective map
$$K^{\times}/N_{L/K}(L^{\times}) F^{\times} \rightarrow
\prod_{v \in S}  (\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^2/\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})
= \prod_{v \in S}
 (\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z}).$$
In particular, if $S$ is arbitrarily large, then the first group is infinite.
Now $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F) = (\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^2$, and the condition on $v$ is that $\mathrm{Frob}_v$ is the order $2$ element generating $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. By Cebotarev, this happens for a set of $v$ of density $1/4$ an in particular to infinitely many, so the original group is infinite. Now this is by no means the hardest case of Cebotarev, but actually slightly more work shows that this quotient is infinite if and only if there exist infinitely many $v$ of this form.
